# How Can PHP connect to mysql with localhost user and specific bind address

Tags: php, mysql

My Apache and mysql server are installed on the same linux server.
In my mysql configuration file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I have this line:

```
bind-address = 192.168.0.12
```

In my mysql database, I have a user `db_user` who can only connect from `localhost`

```
User     Server      Password   Global privileges  "Grant"
db_user  localhost   Yes        USAGE              No
```

What I don't understand is: how can php connect to mysql tables with db_user and localhost domain if mysql is configured as binding only 192.168.0.12?

I checked the hosts file, localhost send to 127.0.0.1 and not 192.168.0.12.

And the other thing, this command on the server works :

> mysql -udb_user -p"password" thedatabase

Comment: It should not. Have you restarted the mysql server after configuration?

Comment: Yes, in fact it is working like this since a long time. I was just wondering why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `localhost` as the host to connect to, [MySQL will use a socket](https://serverfault.com/a/337844), and not a TCP connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your routing in order to make your server connect to `192.168.0.12` instead of `127.0.0.1`. It knows that `192.168.0.12` is the localhost and thus uses `127.0.0.1` instead of `192.168.0.12`.